# ¿ Como puedo obtener la cantidad de paginas de un documento word en JS puro?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, knockoutjs, docx

Comienzo por aclarar que no tengo conocimiento en JS, actualmente tengo una solicitud en la que cual debo obtener la cantidad de paginas de cada documento que se suba a una aplicación, pudiendo ser .pfd, .doc y .docx.

Ya tengo una función en JavaScript para obtener la cantidad de paginas de los .pdf, pero me falta para los documento word, debo hacerlo en JavaScript puro, puesto es que es una aplicación bastante vieja.

La función para obtener la cantidad de paginas de los .pfd es:

```
if (file.type == "application/pdf")
            {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    var count = reader.result.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
                    $(`#Pages_${e.target.id}`).prop('textContent', count)
                    console.log('Number of Pages:', count);
                }
            }
```

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando con Node?

Comment: no te serviría cambiar "pdf" del primer ir por "docx"?
Osea:  file.type == "application/docx"

Comment: 1- No se esta usando Node y no puedo hacer uso de él.
2- En cuanto a la segunda consulta, no serviría el cambio ya que la función sirve únicamente para .pdf, debido a eso tengo esa validación, ya que sin ella y si llega un docx o doc, fallaría.

Comment: No le he leido, pero quizá te venga util https://docx.js.org/#/usage/page-numbers